# Using Raspberry Pi as an IP packer encrypter but only for certain IP Adresses

Tags: encryption, ip, raspberry-pi, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I am trying to create a program that will, on the raspberry pi, analyze all IP packets leaving a "Private" Network and if the packet destination is one that needs its packets encrypted, it should basically for lack of better term, intercept and encrypt that packet and then send it. All other packets for now can be dropped. SO i am just starting with it and I have gotten my pi to give me the information of incoming IP packets via TCPDump and Tshark.

I am trying to figure out how to, in C or in python, be able to compare the address of the packet to a known IP address and for now, just up a count or print that it was a match. I do not know if there is a library of functions I should install on the pi that can give me the address in a str or int, or could someone help me on the first step on how to make this function. Any documents, webpages, etc.

I would love any helping hints possible. If you need any more information please ask.
Thank You

Comment: This is a bit too high level for stackoverflow. You should do this step by step. Choose for instance C, and check out what is available to sniff/capture IP packets. If you run into trouble doing that, ask a specific question here. Note that you seem to be trying to create a VPN solution. I would recommend you to check out OpenVPN.

Comment: When I used to mess with stuff there was a library called libpcap from the tcpdump people to capture low-level packets.